# Como envio um array multidimenssional atraves de um post para receber em um formulario?? em php

Tags: php, array, formulário, post

```
<?php

$funcionarios = array(
array("nome" => "Pedro", "idade" => 24, "salario" => 2245.32, "filhos" =>3, "ativo" => true),
array("nome" => "Rossana", "idade" => 35, "salario" => 1845.34, "filhos" =>2, "ativo" => true),
array("nome" => "Everaldo", "idade" => 41, "salario" => 8302.50, "filhos" =>0, "ativo" => true),
array("nome" => "Caroline", "idade" => 27, "salario" => 4323.63, "filhos" =>1, "ativo" =>false),);
$gratificacao = 10;

foreach($funcionarios as $funcionario){
if($funcionario["ativo"]){
$funcionario["salario"] += ($funcionario["salario"] * ($gratificacao/100)) + (238.54 * $funcionario["filhos"]);
echo "Funcionario: {$funcionario['nome']} - {$funcionario['salario']} <br>";
} else {
echo "Funcionario: {$funcionario['nome']} - INATIVO <br>";
}
}
$envia = serialize($funcionarios);
echo "</br></br>$envia";
/*
<form method="POST" action="pagina2.php"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="array" value="<?php echo $envia; ?>"/>
</form>
*/
?>
```

Comment: Oi, Robson. Descreva melhor o problema, veja: [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que entendi você quer usar revernizar seu php no HTML, para fazer isso basta usar o php no seu html.

```
insira o código aqui
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Formulário</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </head>


    <body>
<!--        A tabela que vai mostra os dados do seu PHP -->
        <div id="table">
            <table  border="1px" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Valor</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
 $funcionarios = array(
array("nome" => "Pedro", "idade" => 24, "salario" => 2245.32, "filhos" =>3, "ativo" => true),
array("nome" => "Rossana", "idade" => 35, "salario" => 1845.34, "filhos" =>2, "ativo" => true),
array("nome" => "Everaldo", "idade" => 41, "salario" => 8302.50, "filhos" =>0, "ativo" => true),
array("nome" => "Caroline", "idade" => 27, "salario" => 4323.63, "filhos" =>1, "ativo" =>false),);
$gratificacao = 10;

foreach($funcionarios as $funcionario){
if($funcionario["ativo"]){
$funcionario["salario"] += ($funcionario["salario"] * ($gratificacao/100)) + (238.54 * $funcionario["filhos"]);
echo "Funcionario: {$funcionario['nome']} - {$funcionario['salario']} <br> 
             <tr>
                <td>{$funcionario['nome']} - {$funcionario['salario']}</td>
            </tr> ";
        
        }
else {
echo "Funcionario: {$funcionario['nome']} - INATIVO <br>
<tr>
                <td>{$funcionario['nome']} - INATIVO </td>
            </tr>
";

}
}
$envia = serialize($funcionarios);
echo "</br></br>$envia";


                    
                ?>
            </table>

    </body>
</html>
```